# Combine two commands into one statement

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

In Linux I have the following `RUN`:

```
RUN dotnet restore Backend &&\
    dotnet publish Backend --output /opt/src/Publish
```

Now I try to do it for windows container:

```
RUN dotnet restore IPBackend &\
    dotnet publish IPBackend --output /app/publish
```

However I get this message:

```
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for
future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as
part of a string.
```

For `&&` it also throws an error.
I fixed it by the following code:

```
RUN dotnet restore Backend ;\
    dotnet publish Backend --output /app/publish
```

It works fine but I try to understand whether is it correct way or not?
If yes could anybody give a link with description?

Comment: I'm using docker for windows and using && in run gives: The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version. Is there a correct way to chain RUN?

Answer (score -1):

'&&' is for command chaining it will execute command based on succesfull execution of previous command. ';' doesnt care for result of previous command and will execute even when previous command is failed.

'&' you can fork your 2 commands so a command will start executing without waiting for previous command to finish.

I would like 2 see errors you encountered with &&

Comment: `The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.` Please pay attention it is executed in context of docker for windows. P.S. Downvote is not from me.

Comment: this is not relevant at all as this post is for docker. You are also wrong, single `&` does wait for previous command to finish, but is not relying on exitcode, so will execute regardless of previous command's exitcode, where `&&` will not execute second command if first was not errorlevel 0

Comment: @Serg046 sorry, the comment was meant for the Blinsniper.

Comment: Yeah, I got you correctly, just to remind. I would like to have analog of `&&`...

Comment: @GerhardBarnard that is interesting let me check it